# Triggering a mail through Unix Script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, putty, mailx

I am trying to prepare a unix script that can send a mail to Users if a certain condition mets or fails in the scripts. I know about ‘mailx’

echo ‘Condition met’ | mailx rishabh123@outlook.com

but instead of writing the mail body, I want to send the mail which I have stored in a path for eg.

Path: /prod/data/mail.txt

Comment: `mailx rishabh123@outlook.com < /prod/data/mail.txt`?

Comment: I tried this but it is not picking up the content from the file.